# How to automate adding external scripts into the main script code with bash

Tags: bash, automation, sh

Note: please give feedback on the title, I honest didn't know how to title this question.

Im trying to design a code that everytime the user drop a file in the `tools` folder, it automatic gets add into the main code at `menu.sh` script, so it's simpler for the user.

The menu.sh is working fine, but everytime the user adds a new script he needs to do add two lines of code in the main script(`menu.sh`)

for example, lets say the user want to add a script called `run-scrape.sh`

```
"run-scrape" need to be added:
-options variable
-added in the source command inside the case statment
```

I am trying to automate this two tasks so it's simpler for the user.

I am open to a different approach to do this or link to something similar, I couldn't find anything like.

##### Background:

folder structure:

```
~ 
scripts  
menu.sh, tools 
> cd tools
pushing-code.sh,  purge-data.sh, run-scrape.sh
```

menu.sh :

```
title="title"

prompt="Pick an option(number): "

options=(         
        "pushing code" \
        "purge-data" \
        "run-scrape" \
         )

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt"
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 
    case "$REPLY" in
    0) source $(pwd)/scripts/tools/pushing-code.sh; my_func;;
    0) source $(pwd)/scripts/tools/purge-data.sh; my_func;;
    0) source $(pwd)/scripts/tools/run-scrape.sh; my_func;;

    $((${#options[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;
    esac
```

###### Working the Solution:

basically some how need to create this two components in the menu.sh code:

1. The variable: options

   ```
   myFileNames=$(ls ~/$(pwd)/scripts/tools)
   for file in $myFileNames;
   ```
2. The case statement
   the following line of code will be the same for every file except for the file name, in this example: pushing-code.sh

   so adding this to the menu.sh code:

   ```
   #sample:  0) source $(pwd)/scripts/tools/pushing-code.sh; my_func;

   path=$(pwd)
   args=()
   for i in myFileNames; do
       args=("0) source $path/scripts/tools/$i ; my_func;")
   done

   select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 
       case "$REPLY" in args

       $((${#options[@]}+1))) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
       *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;
       esac
   ```

I don't think it's well put together, does anyone have done something similar in the past that would share the code  :)

Comment: Do you have to call the dynamically added scripts as functions with sourcing, or could you make them executable stand-alone scripts that don't have to be sourced?

Comment: hi @BenjaminW. Im more used with python, new to bash. I will search about: `executable stand-alone scripts that don't have to be sourced`.  The goal is to make it easier for the user to chose an option in the menu and press enter, so is more user friendly and save time

Comment: When you do `source`, the behaviour is as if you typed everything from the file you're sourcing; importantly, sourcing allows you to change the environment by adding functions and variables. A stand-alone script is run in a subshell and cannot change the environment of the shell it's being called from. I suspect the functionality you want to offer from the menu doesn't have to run in the same environment, i.e., wouldn't have to be sourced, which makes everything a little simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: The variable: options
>
> ```
> myFileNames=$(ls ~/$(pwd)/scripts/tools)
> for file in $myFileNames;
> ```

- Use pathname expansion (globbing), not `ls`.
- And use it to populate an array, not a flat string.  Also
- `~/$(pwd)/scripts/tools` does not make sense.

  - If you want to assume that the working directory contains `scripts/` as a subdirectory then just use a relative path (`scripts/tools`).
  - If you want to give a path relative to your home directory then use `~/literal/path/to/scripts/tools`
  - If you want a path relative to the location of the script then see [How do I get the directory where a Bash script is located from within the script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/2402272)

Overall, something along these lines

```
# Create an array of all the *.sh files in the tools directory
options=(/path/to/tools/*.sh)
```

You can check the result by, for example,

```
echo "${options[@]}"
```

---

> 2: The case statement the following line of code will be the same for
> every file except for the file name, in this example: pushing-code.sh

Having the options in an array, you can access each one via its index.  That pairs nicely with using `select`, something along these lines:

```
# Select from among elements of the options array
select choice in "${options[@]}"; do
  if [[ -n "$choice" ]]; then
    # read and evaluate the commands from the selected file
    # select options are numbered from 1, but array indices from 0
    source "${options[$((choice - 1))]}"
    break
  else
    echo "$REPLY" is not a valid selection
    # ...
  fi
done
```

The `select` command will automatically loop until a `break` command is executed or EOF is reached on the standard input.

Comment: It totally makes sense, it's a very well put together and detailed answer. I will test the code and mark as the answer in about one hour from now, sorry im eating lunch

Comment: @Jonh Bollinger, Im getting a error: `scripts/menu.sh: line 38: scripts/tools/pushing-code.sh: division by 0 (error token is "tools/pushing-code.sh")` "

The error occurr in the line: `source "${options[$((choice - 1))]}"`

do you have any hints on how should I adjust it?

Comment: @Peter, the question is tagged [bash].  If you're not actually running this in `bash` (as in, if the script's shebang line is not `#!/bin/bash`) then you may need to change `source` to `.`.

Comment: thank you for the hint, I was running `sh script_name`, it's my bad